# Jquery Date Format - Double Digits

Tags: jquery, date, formatting

Good morning, Does anyone know how to amend this countdown code so that it always outputs at double digits, i.e. 01 01 01, rather than 1 1 1

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();
var end;

if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 14, 0, 0, 0);    
} else {
end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 13, 0, 0, 0);
}

var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
ar diff = new Date(timeleft);

$("#countdownTimer").html(diff.getHours() + "&nbsp;" + diff.getMinutes() + "&nbsp;" +     diff.getSeconds());

}, 1000);

});

</script>
```

Thank you guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a date library, or a simple padding function like this:

```
function padNumber(num, size){
   var s = "0000000000" + num;
   return s.substr(s.length - size);
}
```

So for your code:

```
$("#countdownTimer").html(padNumber(diff.getHours(), 2) + "&nbsp;" 
        + padNumber(diff.getMinutes(), 2) + "&nbsp;" 
        + padNumber(diff.getSeconds(), 2));
```

**Note:** *This simple function does not check the length of the num itself, so specifying too small a size will truncate it (but you get the idea).*

While not bullet proof, this is faster than the 3 best options on the link provided here: [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

**jsPerf:** http://jsperf.com/left-zero-pad/14

**Or if you want even simpler and faster** (but only for 2 digits)

```
function pad2(num){
    if(num < 10){
        return "0" + num;
    }
    return "" + num;
}
```

Note: This last version is *soooo* fast it leaves the other options for dead (something like 20 times faster).

Comment: @dmt: Kind of you to say. For your specific 2-digit usage, go with the last version. It is at least 20 times faster than anything else I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

this simple function should do the trick.

```
function makeTwoDigit(num)
{
          num = num.toString();
          if(num.length==1)
            return "0"+num;
          return num;
};



setInterval(function () {
          var now = new Date();
          var day = now.getDay();
          var end;
          if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 14, 0, 0, 0);    
          } else {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 13, 0, 0, 0);
          }
          var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
          var diff = new Date(timeleft);
          console.log(makeTwoDigit(diff.getHours()) + " " + makeTwoDigit(diff.getMinutes()) + " " +     makeTwoDigit(diff.getSeconds()));
        }, 1000);
```